# How to stop a form from moving

Tags: html, css, browser, web, resize

I have created a website however when I shrink the browser the website stays in position, apart from the form.

If anyone know's how I can stop the form from moving, I will be very grateful.

I have tried position: relative and white-space: no-wrap; but still no luck.

Thanks in advanced

Unique

My Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/r5cu1157/

```
#form-holder {
float: left;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
padding-left: 100px;
padding-top: 30px;
display: block;
*display: block;
white-space: nowrap;}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "moving"?  in which direction is it moving?

Comment: I think you want a responsive form, try to use some CSS framework like bootstrap or foundation, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form to be center aligned then do a

```
Margin: 0 auto;
```

remove the float left and i would suggest to stay away from specifying a height of elements

http://jsfiddle.net/r5cu1157/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS that I have for my container that holds my table and forms, could try   using it for your form, I believe it is a mix of position and margin:

```
.container
{
position: relative;
top: 250px;
background-color: #877CB0;
margin:0 auto; 
text-align: center;
}
```